# Intersection of point normal to plane

Tags: vectors, plane-curves

Hi if I have a point **p** (red dot) and I have a plane **P** (yellow) how do I find the intersection of the point normal to the plane? thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the plane is given as 
$$
Ax + By + Cz = 0
$$
and the point $P$ is $(a, b, c)$. THen the ray from $P$ normal to the plane consists of points of the form
$$
R(t) = (a, b, c) + t(A, B, C)
$$
For what $t$ is $R(t)$ on the plane? We must have
$$
A (a + tA) + B(b + tB) + C(c + tC) = 0 \\
aA + bB + cC + t(A^2 + B^2 + C^2) = 0 \\
t = -\frac{aA +bB + cC}{A^2+B^2+C^2}
$$
Plugging this in as $t$ in $R(t)$ gets you the intersection point $Q$:
$$
Q = (a, b, c) -\frac{aA +bB + cC}{A^2+B^2+C^2} (A, B, C).
$$

Comment: thanks so much... The equation R(t) = (a,b,c) +t (A,B,C)  is that a standard equation? if so what is it called in math books?

Comment: It's "the parametric form for a line" (or a ray), written in vector form.